# objects repeating themselves

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to do a lesson, learning javascript objects and so forth... I am having a problem with this for in loop and I suppose the object literal itself

```
var darkness = { 
  add: function(a,b) {
  for(var title in b) {
      alert(a+ " is the "+ b.title );
      alert(a+ " holds many of"+b.dream);
    }
  }
};


darkness.add('darkness',{
  title :'feelings',
  dream:'dreams'
 });
```

This alerts twice?  test http://jsbin.com/ogunor/1/edit

Can someone help me learn these a little better

Comment: You don't need to loop: http://jsbin.com/ogunor/3/edit

Comment: Haha no wonder why. thanks elclanrs so can we do more with these? like `title: function() {},`  and if so how do we assign it like b.title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain. The `b` object you pass has two properties: title and dream. your `for(var title in b)` loop, will go over each of the object properties key.. meaning will run twice - the first iteration will have `title = 'title'` and the second `title='dream'`. In each iteration you alert twice - thus getting 4 alerts. You can remove the loop completely only keeping the alerts for it to alert only twice.

```
var darkness = { 
  add: function(a,b) {
  for(var title in b) { // runs twice cuz you have 2 properties
      alert(title); // try alerting title just to see what it hold in each iteration.
      alert(a+ " is the "+ b.title );
      alert(a+ " holds many of"+b.dream);
    }
  }
};


darkness.add('darkness',{
  title :'feelings', // 1st property
  dream:'dreams' // 2nd property
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is alerting twice beacuse you are looping through every property (`title` and `dream`) in the `b` object.

This is enough:

```
var darkness = { 
    add: function(a,b) {
        alert(a+ " is the "+ b.title );
        alert(a+ " holds man of " +b.dream);
    }  
};

darkness.add('darkness',{
  title :'feelings',
  dream:'dreams'
});
```